# Member function proxy in a collection using boost

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a collection of object pointers in a map and in several places I need to iterate over the collection and invoke a member function of each object.

At the moment for each member function I need to invoke on every element in the collection I am adding a proxy function which iterates over the collection invoking the associated member.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use boost to create a template function in the collection class which will handle this for me in the generic case?

ANSWER: It turns out this is very easy, modified my original example so that it works as desired:

```
class Object
{
public:
    void func1();
    void func2(int a);
};

class ObjectCollection : public std::map<std::string, Object*>
{
public:
    template <typename Func>
    void invokeMember(Func func)
    {
        for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
        {
            it->second->func();
        }
    }
};

void test()
{
    ObjectCollection collection;
    // ...
    collection.invokeMember(boost::bind(&Object::func1, _1));
    collection.invokeMember(boost::bind(&Object::func2, _1, 42));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
boost::bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(i);      // x.f(i)
```

Taken from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_algorithms)

If you want to have different functions with different parameters, you could have an enum to identify the function (which you pass to invokeMember), pass a variable number of parameters to invokeMember, and call bind in there.

Rather than a variable number of parameters, it might be better to have a class which contains all possible parameters (or pass a `void *` which points to a class which defines the parameters for that function call and use dynamic cast).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'll try it out and see where I can get with it.

Comment: Turns out it's really simple, it worked exactly as I wanted it to, I just needed to add the _1 placeholder to my binds.